# Member function implemented outside of the class body when using template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I've got a templated class that uses a template parameter (`std::enable_if_t`) to restrict the main template parameter as shown here:

```
template <typename T, typename
 = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>>
class Foo 
{
void foo();
}

template<typename T>
void Foo<T>::foo() {} // compiler complains
```

I know I could work around this using `static_assert`, but I'd like to know what the correct approach would be in this case.

I suppose I could simply copy both template parameters again, but that seems very odd to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add the second template parameter:

```
// ..................vvvvvvvvvv
template<typename T, typename U>
void Foo<T, U>::foo() {} // compiler doesn't complains anymore
// ........^^
```

or, maybe better, implement the method inside the class:

```
template <typename T, typename
 = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>>
class Foo 
{
void foo() {}
// .......^^^
};
```

Anyway... take into account that your way to use SFINAE to restrict the type of the (first) parameter has a defect: you are operating over the *default* value of the second template parameter, so it can be bypassed by explicitly including the second template parameter in instantiations.

I mean... you can correctly define a type when `T` is arithmetic:

```
Foo<int> f; // compile
```

and correctly doesn't compile when `T` isn't arithmetic:

```
Foo<void> f; // compilation error
```

But, it compiles (when `T` isn't arithmetic) when you explicitly include a second template parameter:

```
Foo<void, void>  f; // compiles!!!
```

I suppose you don't wont that `Foo<void, void>` to compile.

To avoid this problem, you can use SFINAE on the left side of the equal sign, deleting the template parameter, not the default value.

For example, you can write:

```
template <typename T,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, bool> = true>
class Foo 
{
void foo() {}
};
```

This way, you're sure nobody can instantiate a `Foo` object when the first template parameter isn't an arithmetic type.

This solution has a little problem (or maybe not... depends on what you expect): you can define two different classes over the same `T` parameter.

I mean... you can define:

```
Foo<int>        f0;
Foo<int, true>  f1;  // same type as f0
Foo<int, false> f2;  // different type from f0 and f1
```

To avoid this, for the type of the second parameter, you can use a type that accepts a single value. For example: `std::nullptr_t`

```
template <typename T, 
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
class Foo 
{
void foo() {}
};
```

Now, you can have a `Foo<int>`, that is shorthand for `Foo<int, nullptr>`, but not a class that differs in the second template parameter.

Comment: I've seen `std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>>* = nullptr` (`void* = nullptr`) more than the version with `bool`.

Comment: @yeputons - Is another way to apply SFINAE to the parameter and not to the default value... my preferred is using `std::nullptr_t`, so you're sure that you can't define different classes that differ in the second argument...

Answer (score 2):

You could make the SFINAE a nested template, within the class, to restrict the type at the function.

SFINAE as a nested template:

```
// class declaration
template <typename T>
class Foo;

// class definition
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
void foo();

template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<U> > >
void somefunction(U val);   // function declaration
};

// somefunction definition
template <typename T>
template <typename U, typename>
void Foo<T>::somefunction(U val) {// *** code here *** //;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this syntax, because the compile time error message is at least somewhat readable:

- msvc : `main.cpp(21,22): error C2079: 's' uses undefined class 'Foo<std::string,void>'`
- gcc : `main.cpp:21:22: error: aggregate ‘Foo > s’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined`

---

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename type_t, typename enable_t = void>
class Foo;

template <typename type_t>
class Foo<type_t, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<type_t>>>
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "foo\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> f;
    Foo<std::string> s;
    f.foo();
    return 0;
}
```